# In QCD, Why the order parameter of chiral symmetry takes the form $\langle0 \lvert \bar{\psi}\psi\rvert 0 \rangle$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, gauge-invariance

A simple question, why the order parameter of QCD chiral symmetry (chiral condensate) take this form:

(or let's say why choose $\bar{\psi}\psi$ to judge there is SSB(spontaneous symmetry breaking) or not?)
$$\langle0 \lvert \bar{\psi}\psi\rvert 0 \rangle$$
I just figure out the reanson why it reagard as vacuum expectation value ,but also called "condensate":

It's because before quark acquire mass, the production of $\bar{q}q$ pairs don't need  additional energy (since we require the quark pair $\bar{q}q$ have opposite momentum and spin), also the quark pairs can be consider to be a bosonic composite particle, so the ground state of system should be the condensed state with a bunch of quark pairs $\bar{q}q$, it will not be limitted by Pauli exclusion principle, thus we call it "chiral condensate".

Am I right? If this interpretation is correct, is this interpretation has any thing to do with we take the form  $\langle0 \lvert \bar{\psi}\psi\rvert 0 \rangle$ ?

Comment: Due diligence [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210398).

Comment: @Due diligence thanks a lot！